# Camunda API "failedJob" is null

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a business process that is successfully completed in 2-3 hours (depends on the number of records). At the same time, the process is running on the shader every 15 minutes, but the controller is configured so that the new process will not be started while the previous one is running.
However, an error occurs, as in the photo, as I see from the logs, my process is successfully processing and its extreme log is output, and the error occurs in the Camunda API itself. Has anyone encountered or directed where to look?

I have attached two screenshots, the first is the error log, the second is a clipping from the Camunda API with the location of this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/topQW.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeF0n.png)

Now I'm trying to speed up the process to adequate limits, because I suspect that this may be the problem. I am also seriously thinking about removing transactionality over the controller running in the process.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557